# unable to get graphs using jp gc generator in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am unable to view graphs even after installing the plugins from the **jmeter-plugins.org** site.

I can view the **jpgc graph** in the listener but on running only **csv** is getting created not the graphs.

I am not getting any error message but it shows warnings. I followed all steps properly as mentioned in [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BuPnFUl2iY).

Below is the error log:

```
2017/02/22 16:07:49 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2017/02/22 16:07:49 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2017/02/22 16:07:49 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2017/02/22 16:07:50 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2017/02/22 16:07:50 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 10 threads for group Thread Group. 
2017/02/22 16:07:50 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2017/02/22 16:07:50 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 10 ramp-up 5 perThread 500.0 delayedStart=false 
2017/02/22 16:07:50 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2017/02/22 16:07:50 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2017/02/22 16:07:50 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2017/02/22 16:07:50 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2 
2017/02/22 16:07:51 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-3 
2017/02/22 16:07:51 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-4 
2017/02/22 16:07:52 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-5 
2017/02/22 16:07:52 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-6 
2017/02/22 16:07:53 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-7 
2017/02/22 16:07:53 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-8 
2017/02/22 16:07:54 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-9 
2017/02/22 16:07:54 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-10 
2017/02/22 16:07:57 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1 
2017/02/22 16:07:57 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2017/02/22 16:07:58 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-4 
2017/02/22 16:07:58 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-4 
2017/02/22 16:07:59 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-3 
2017/02/22 16:07:59 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-3 
2017/02/22 16:07:59 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-2 
2017/02/22 16:07:59 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-2 
2017/02/22 16:08:00 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-7 
2017/02/22 16:08:00 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-7 
2017/02/22 16:08:00 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-5 
2017/02/22 16:08:00 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-5 
2017/02/22 16:08:00 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-8 
2017/02/22 16:08:00 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-8 
2017/02/22 16:08:01 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-9 
2017/02/22 16:08:01 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-9 
2017/02/22 16:08:01 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-6 
2017/02/22 16:08:01 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-6 
2017/02/22 16:08:01 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-10 
2017/02/22 16:08:01 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-10 
2017/02/22 16:08:01 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2017/02/22 16:08:01 INFO  - kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker: Using JMeterPluginsCMD v. N/A 
2017/02/22 16:08:01 WARN  - kg.apc.jmeter.JMeterPluginsUtils: JMeter env exists. No one should see this normally. 
2017/02/22 16:08:01 WARN  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Error encountered during shutdown of kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener@297d7a76 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.SynthesisReportGui
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:237)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:234)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.setPluginType(PluginsCMDWorker.java:73)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:221)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:137)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:215)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:436)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.SynthesisReportGui
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:227)
    ... 7 more

2017/02/22 16:08:01 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/) which is a pre-requisite for Graphs Generator, you can install it either [manually](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-synthesis) or using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) (recommended)

[image: Synthesis Report JMeter PLugins Manager]

Comment: Do we also need to install **JMeter-Extras.jar** in JMeter's `lib/ext` installation direcotry ? I've found [this link](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/) which mentions that it's necessary to install them, but it's it's version 1.4.0 is from 2016 year and I'm using JMeter 5.2.1 verison (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63582566/6805866)).